# Is there a Free-To-Play item that my character can hold in Runescape that increases experience output, even slightly?

Tags: runescape

Not sure if this is a duplicate.I have been playing Runescape for five years now, and I have been wondering if there is an item that I can hold that increases how much experience I can get. For example, if I cut down an oak log, I would normally get about 40 experience. Is there an item that I can hold that will increase this to, let's say, 45 experience or higher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have [urns](https://runescape.wikia/w/Urns) in your inventory that will grant bonus experience in fishing, cooking, mining, smithing, woodcutting and prayer. The lower level urns are free to play items.

Also, cooking on a [bonfire](https://runescape.wikia/w/Bonfire) will slightly increase the cooking xp gained, as will burning logs on a bonfire instead of burning them normally. The lower level bonfires are free to play.

Answer (score 1):

For Runecrafting, you can use one of the three [Runecrafting Gloves](https://runescape.wiki/w/Runecrafting_gloves) to **double** the amount of XP earned when crafting runes of the glove's type.

They have a limited amount of uses, and can only be obtained from [the Fist of Guthix minigame](https://runescape.wiki/w/Fist_of_Guthix), but are, in my opinion, worth the cost.